# How to show values in SweetAlert instead on objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm using sweet alert library with html attr but I need to show some values from loop in the `swal`, all I get is `[object object]` I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
$(".track_details").click(function () {
    var data = $(this).data('val');
    swal({
        title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",
        text: "<div class='row'>\
        <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>Message</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
        <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>Status</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>Datetime</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>City</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
   <div class='col-md-1'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>State</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-1'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>Zip</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
     <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>Country</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    </div> <div class='row my_tracking_swal'></div> \
    " + $.each(data, function (index, val) {
            $("<div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
        <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
        <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-1'>\
    <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-1'>\
       <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    <div class='col-md-2' >\
     <strong>\
            <span>" + val.tracking_status + "</span>\
        </strong>\
    </div>\
    ").appendTo(".my_tracking_swal");
        }),

        html: true
    }) ;

});
```

where my data value is look like `[{'tracking_status':'value'},{'tracking_status':'value'},{'tracking_status':'value'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are concatenating String with an Object. That is why you receive `[object object]` string as result.

You'd better **create an HTML String from data Array** separately 
and then concatenate it with HTML you paste inside `swal`.

This will help:

```
var data = $(this).data('val');

var myTrackingContent = data.map(function(item) { 
    return "<div class='col-md-2'><strong><span>" + item.tracking_status + "</span> </strong></div>";
}).join('');

swal({
    title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",
    text: "...<div class='row my_tracking_swal'>" + myTrackingContent + "</div>...",
    html: true
}) ;
```

Comment: let me try that and get back to you :)

Comment: So, any success?)