# How to show values from array in content of SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I have an array which contains some strings :

```
//declaration
let arrayOfStrings = [];

// contains data under this form when console.log(arrayOfStrings);

(3) ['string0','string1','string2']
```

I am using SweetAlert2 library and I would like to show in popup all values from the *arrayOfStrings * array but all I get is "undefined".

My code is:

```
let getData=() =>{arrayOfStrings.map((data) => { return '<p>' + { data } + '</p>'; }).join('');};

//[...]

Swal.fire({
      title: 'Title',
      icon: 'warning',
      showClass: {
         popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
      },
      hideClass: {
         popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp'
      },
      html: 'My text is:<br/> ' + getData(),
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Title'
}).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
            // do something
      }
});
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416772/how-to-show-values-in-sweetalert-instead-on-objects) method but the only content in popup is "My text is:
"
Thank you!

This is the logic it works.. I know it is not the best but I just need it to work for now

```
//Component 1:
const [showTable, setShowTable]= useState(false)

//In component 1 call Component 2 with showTable as prop 
<Component2 showTable={showTable}/>
//Inside Component2 I do props.showTable(true);
<SomeIcon onClick={()=>props.showTable(true)}/>
//in Component1 :

useEffect(()=>{ getTableData(); }, [showTable] );

const getTableData = () =>{
  getDatasetPreview(arg1, arg2, arg3).then(
     data =>{
       if(data) { arrayOfStrings.push('[\'' + data.columns[index] + '\']')); }
     }
  )
};
// getDataset is a async function with a .get call to endpoint
//In other useEffect I showUp the SweetAlert popup
```

Comment: `return` missing from the function - `let getData=() => { return arrayOfStrings.map..... };`

Comment: You should also remove the `{ data }` and use just `data`

Comment: Now appear nothing

Comment: ```let getData= () => arrayOfStrings.map((data) => `<p>${data}</p>`).join('');``` - A couple brakets are useless... Try this. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XWYdmzw?editors=0010)

Comment: This one either

Comment: It works in codenpen... Carefully check ;)

Comment: @PTMAndrey How are you adding data into `arrayOfStrings`?

Comment: OK.. it works with this example but my real array in code is something like this:
(2) ["['lastName']", "['firstName']"] 
and shows nothing. I need the single quotes because I sent those fields into a python script.

Is it possible to be conflicts of quotes or something like this?

Comment: @NickParsons arrayOfStrings.push('[\'' + data.columns[index] + '\']'));

Comment: @PTMAndrey hm, I thought in your question you said it contained `['string0','string1','string2']`... You should be using just `.push(data.columns[index])`, although that won't change if the data shows a result or not. Are you using `.push()` inside of a callback of some sort? Where does `data` from from?

Comment: If those pushes are made after page load... Like in the callback of an ajax request, the array is empty when Swal runs. You should then have Swal running in that callback too... If that is unclear, then update your question with the relevant infos.

Comment: [Update] the code I made is in question

Comment: @PTMAndrey Are you sure that when you run `Swal.fire()` the array `arrayOfStrings` has data in it. Using `console.log()` logs a reference at the time of viewing the log, not the value at the time of performing the log, so it's not that reliable, log a primitive value instead by using `console.log(arrayofStrings.length)` to see if it contains more than `0` items.

Comment: SweetAlert works outside of the React tree... So you won't be able to use useEfect for its content. Even "Sweetalert2 with React support" shows this warning. Please have a look at [sweetalert2-react-content](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content). - You should look for a React popup component. There is a ton.

Comment: Thank you everyone for help!